# Php Sql get first value of Array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

How can I acces first value and second value of this foreach seperatly?

```
foreach($database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1') as $resultRandom) {

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*separately*"?

Comment: I want to print out the first lets say firstname which has a cat value of 1 into a variable and the second one the same way into an variable

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this from what I think you are saying:

```
$query = "SELECT `id`, `firstname`, `lastname` FROM `staff` WHERE `categorie_bit` = 1";
$rows = [];
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($database->query($query)))
{
    $rows[] = [
        "id"=>$result['id'],
        "firstName"=>$result['firstname'],
        "lastName"=>$result['lastname']
        ];
}
var_dump($rows);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?
$query= "SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);


print "<table width=600 border=1>\n";
while ($get_info = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
print "<tr>\n";
foreach ($get_info as $field)
print "\t<td>$field</td>\n";
print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: still suggesting mysql_* function ?

Comment: @dynamic Done with Editing